# Array list of double in SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to know whether it is possible to save as an array list of double in SharedPreference. In my application, I want the 'size' to be saved whenever there is new 'size' written from the user. It must be uploaded to an array list of double, without erasing the previous one.

Comment: that is not what shared preferences is for. Use a file object or a database

Comment: Then, if I use a file, how can I upload the value as an array list of double?

Comment: If you use a file you can check out serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all - the answer to your question is simple:

it's **not** possible.

but the good news are that there are lots of ways saving array of doubles (as you've been suggested in the comments):

save it to a binary file / serialized file in the internal/external storage, to SQLite database, make it the responsibility of the server side (if there is one..)

you can save the size of the array in the shared preferences if it helps you read the data from the file containing the serialized array, but I guess you already know that..

anyway - good luck

Comment: Then, is it possible to save those double type values in a file with Datastream? The main point is that the new value added should not erase the previous one, and all the values could be read as an Arraylist of double to draw a line graph.

Comment: @user1453296: that's not suppose to be a problem, because you can desirialize the data to the memory (hold reference to it), do your changes on the object (add items), and then write from scratch to the file the new array.   another option is to use random acess file, which allow you to add bytes exactly where you won't directly to the file, without delete anything